# django tests - model instance not created

Tags: python, django, django-testing, django-tests, model-mommy

I'm experiencing issues on creating fixtures for a particular model in a test class with Django and the DRF. I'm using [model-mommy](https://model-mommy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html), but even creating a single instance just using the Django ORM for that model does not work:

```py
    from rest_framework.test import APIRequestFactory, APITestCase
    from model_mommy import mommy

    from api.v1 import views
    from company.models.models import CompanyUserProfile, ManagerRelation, DynamicRelation


    User = get_user_model()


    class APIViewsTestCase(APITestCase):

        @classmethod
        def setUpTestData(cls):
            supervisory_id = "1337"
            emp_group_id = "119"
            prd_scope_id = "1334"
            user = mommy.make(User)
            setattr(cls, 'user', user)
            company_user_profile_1 = mommy.make(CompanyUserProfile)
            requestor = mommy.make(
                CompanyUserProfile, is_manager=True,
                supervisory_id=supervisory_id, emp_group_id=emp_group_id,
                prd_scope_id=prd_scope_id, user=user
            )
            cls.user = user
            manager_relation = mommy.make(
                ManagerRelation, manager_id=requestor.id, mgr_type="Direct Mgr", _quantity=5
            )
            dynamic_relations = mommy.make(
                DynamicRelation,target_id=requestor.id, _quantity=5
            )

        def setUp(self) -> None:
            super().setUp()
            self.client.force_authenticate(user=self.user)

        def test_employee_view(self):
            CompanyUserProfile.objects.create(
                guid=uuid.uuid4(),
                csod_user_id='idcbijnccdocwocd', csod_username='djchbdcjnwdskjcn',
                id=3333
            )
            print('cup count:', CompanyUserProfile.objects.count())
            print('user count:', User.objects.count())
            print('m_rels count:', ManagerRelation.objects.count())
            print('d_rels count:', DynamicRelation.objects.count())
            rsp = self.client.get('/api/v1/employees/')
            self.assertEqual(rsp.status_code, HTTPStatus.OK)
```

however `CompanyUserProfile` records are not created, both using `mommy.make` or `CompanyUserProfile.objects.create`:

```
-- test run output
Creating test database for alias 'default'...
System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
cup count: 0
user count: 1
m_rels count: 5
d_rels count: 5
Destroying test database for alias 'default'...
```

`CompanyUserProfile` inherits from `AbstractCornerstoneUserProfile` (abstract base model), that's the main difference between this and the other models.

Any idea of what can be the root cause of this?

Comment: Do not add SOLVED to the title of your question to indicate that you already have a solution, instead we invite you to post an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UPDATE:
solved -> 100% my fault, the custom `ModelManager` of `CompanyUserProfile` was excluding created objects on `CompanyUserProfile.objects.count()`.